# Connection refused when sending email using Scrapy mail module

Tags: python, email, scrapy, mail-sender

I am trying to send email after scraping using Scrapy, but I get this error:

```
2017-02-25 12:44:44 [scrapy.mail] ERROR: Unable to send mail: To=['<my_email>@gmail.com'] Cc=['<my_email>@gmail.com'] Subject="Test" Attachs=0- Connection was refused by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..
```

This is the code:

```
    mailer = scrapy.mail.MailSender.from_settings(scrapy.conf.settings)
    mailer.send(to=["<my_email>@gmail.com"], subject="Test", 
        body="Test", cc=["<my_email>@gmail.com"])
```

How can I send email successfully using Scrapy `MailSender()`

Answer (score 0):

To send email you need an SMTP server that allows you to send email, and to configure the connection to that SMTP server through [mail settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/email.html#mail-settings) like `MAIL_HOST` and `MAIL_PORT`.

If you search the internet for the name of your email provider (e.g. Kolab Now, Google Mail) and "SMTP", you should be able to find the settings you need to use.